# How do I get the results from a forEach method on an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a project that displays a table of user submitted data, 'entries'.

I have my project set up to pull the entry objects out of the entries array, and construct the tables with the appropriate data.

One cell in the table, is a checkbox. Each entry's checkbox has a value that corresponds to the entries ID number.

I am trying to add Edit, Delete functionality to this table.

I have a function that checks all of the checkboxes and returns an array of the values from the selected entries. This array is checkedEntries.

I am trying to take checkedEntries, and for each index of this array, I want it to search the main entries array for an object with a matching ID. I then want it to pull those objects out, and store them in a new array, pulledEntries.

I believe I am on the right track, but I am unsure of how to access the result of the forEach method. I do not wish to use JQuery.

Here's my code: Javascript

```
function pullEntries(arr) {
  arr.forEach(entry => entries.find(item => {
    if (entry === item.id)
      return true;
    // push entry object into pulledEntries
    pulledEntries.push(idk?); // what would I use to reference it here? 
  }))
}
```

Comment: You should use map instead of forEach. forEach does not return anything but map does. That's the difference between them. Here is a helpful link to map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

A simplification of one of the other answers:

```
function pullEntries(arr) {
  return arr.map(entry => entries.find(item => entry === item.id));
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChechoCZ said, using `.map` instead of `.forEach` will return the results in the form of an array. However, this is ES6 syntax I believe.

The ES6 way:

```js
function pullEntries(arr) {
  return arr.map(entry => entries.find(item => {
    if (entry === item.id)
      return true;
    return false;
  }))
}
// returns a result looking like [true, true, false, true, false, false]
```

The ES5 way:

```js
function pullEntries(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    return entries.find(function(item) {
      if (entry === item.id)
        newArr.push(true);
      else
        newArr.push(false);
    });
  });
  return newArr;
}
// returns a result looking like [true, true, false, true, false, false]
```

Comment: ES5 doesn't support arrow functions (at forEach).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I completely missed that!

Comment: (Arrow functions are not required and add no value [except from a slightly shorter syntax] in this usage of map.)

Comment: Wdym arrow functions aren't required? Doesn't map expect a callback as a parameter?

Comment: Sure, it does. An "normal" anonymous function works fine. Aside from syntax, the _only_ difference between an arrow and "normal" anonymous function is the binding of `this` (or lack of).

Comment: I just like arrow functions for the look and compactness. ES5 syntax works perfectly fine the same way.

Comment: So, that's wim with arrow functions are not required, which is a true statement regardless of personal preference in cases where the usages does not make a semantic difference: `arr.map(function (entry) { return .. })`.